# error using stream package/data type

Tags: haskell

I have been stuck with a particular situation. I am not sure what the error even is to be honest.

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)
streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons x (Stream xs)) = x: streamToList (Stream xs)
```

Doing something like this, I got **Not in scope : data constructor 'Stream'**, so I googled the error and some solutions were to change stream to a lower case

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)
streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons x xs) = x: streamToList (stream xs)
```

But then I get **Parse error in pattern : stream**

I tried importing **Data.Stream** (googled on Hoogle) but **Could not find module 'Data.Stream'**

Currently using Haskell from Ubuntu packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
streamToList :: Stream a -> [a]
streamToList (Cons x xs) = x : streamToList xs
```

`Stream` is the name of a type, so it can be used on the right-hand side of `::`. But it is not a data constructor, so it cannot be used as a value or in pattern matches.

`Cons` is the name of a data constructor, so it can be used as a value or in pattern matches. But it is not a type.

Comment: How would I go about to test my functionality? Using Cons considering it is the data constructor? would I also derive the Show, Eq, Ord?

Comment: @BaoThai You can derive them but those typeclasses aren't very useful on an infinite stream.

Comment: Would I have to derive it as instance Show a => Show (Stream a -> String) or? @ephemient

Comment: @BaoThai Manually, it would be `instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where show :: Stream a -> String`. If you add `deriving Show` to the original `data` you'll get an automatic instance.